# PHP: use a variable as type for convertion

Tags: php

I need something like this:

```
$type = 'double';
$text = '0.90000000000002';
$double = ($type)$text;
```

So I need to use a variable as a type.

Comment: dirty! dirty! dirty! why? though you can use the [setType()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) function

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = '0.90000000000002';
$type = 'float';

$result = settype($text, $type);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php

edit: from that link

> "float" (only possible since PHP 4.2.0, for older versions use the
>   deprecated variant "double")